# How to use <img src=“”> in XSLT

Tags: 2013, xslt

I am using the following code to display image using XSLT in Sharepoint. It is working fine.

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Image">
```

But this approach doesn't allow me to define width and height of image so I tried to use it like this but it didn't work.

```
<img src="{@Image}" width="100" height="100">
```

How to make it work?

Comment: If you do a <xsl:value-of select="@Image" /> what is output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how the @Image is defined, it will sometimes come through with a description separated by a comma.

If this is the case then you could try substring-before:

```
<img src="{substring-before(@Image,',')}" width="100" height="100">
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some folks on Stack Overflow asked a similar question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904/how-do-you-add-an-image-in-xslt

Few choices over there to try. Good luck.